# How to add spell-checking to Fedora 17?

Tags: fedora, fedora-17

I installed Fedora 17 but it does not seem to have spell-checking out of the box. I need it for Firefox, Gedit, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to install a spellchecker package. The most popular are myspell and ispell. Choose the appropriate one for your language and install through yum.